# EPUB creation in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, epub

Is there any library out there that I can use to create epub files in .NET/C#? A Flowdocument -> epub conversion tool would be ideal, but any kind of library would be great.

I am also interested in an assesment of how complex it would be to write one. I understand that it is basically a bunch of zipped XHTML files, but I keep hearing that using existing conversion tools it is difficult to get it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try ePub Sharp? Here is the [project page](http://sharpepub.codeplex.com/)
Note: I have not tried it myself.

Comment: I think this project might be dead. I do not see any code on the source forge page.

Comment: The project may not be dead, but it has zero documentation and the usage model is painfully difficult to deduce from the object model. This answer would be more useful if it included some idea how *how* one might use ePubSharp?

Answer (score 2):

I am using the following library from Aspose - http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/default.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I build a `DLL` around epubcheck you can use from .NET by using `IKVM`.

You can download it from here: 
http://www.raulvejar.com/Blog/tabid/70/EntryId/1/EPubCheck-1-1-on-NET.aspx

Comment: Case in point, this page is now gone.  Here is the internet archived version: https://web.archive.org/web/20120116043500/http://www.raulvejar.com/Blog/tabid/70/EntryId/1/EPubCheck-1-1-on-NET.aspx

Answer (score 0):

[DotNetEpub](https://github.com/gonzoua/DotNetEpub) may not have been around when the question was first asked.